# What does it mean in Lua to have a, b = foo()?

Tags: lua

I have searched on line and can not find an explanation for this.

What does the following mean?

```
Local a,b = foo()
```

Why two variables?

Does it mean

```
Local a= foo()
```

And

```
Local b= foo()
```

As well? Or?

Can someone please provide examples of usage?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Is there anything I can do to also make my answer upvote worthy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that foo returns **two** values and they go into a and b! So, foo is called once, but the two results get stored into two variables.

See https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html for further reference.

The syntax is a bit strange, other languages would ask to use braces, like

```
( a, b ) = foo()
```

Kotlin allows for that, too. They call it destructing.

Answer (score 5):

In Lua, a function can return more than one value. For example, this function returns two values:

```
function returnThreeAndFive()
    return 3, 5
end
```

You can load the results of function calls into variables using the syntax you described. (However, if you want the variables to be local, you should use a lower-case "l" for "local", not an upper-case "L".)

```
local a, b = returnThreeAndFive()
print(a, b) -- Prints "3    5"
```

If you use more variables than the function returns values, then Lua fills those in with `nil`.

```
local a, b, c = returnThreeAndFive()
print(a, b, c) -- Prints "3    5    nil"
```

Conversely, if the function returns more values than you use variables for, then you only capture the values that you put in variables.

```
local a = returnThreeAndFive()
print(a) -- Prints "3"
```